# (slightly) advanced linear algebra with objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, linear-algebra

My buddy and I are planning on porting a python app we have to the iOS.  We use numpy's SVD, norm, and [pinv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) functions, which I don't see how to translate to iOS.  I've looked over the [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) documentation and did not see anything for the pinv (I could have missed it though).  What libraries can I use?  If I have multiple options, what are the trade-offs between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run C code in Objective-C, so you can use any C mathematical library.